# Delphi compiler Error: Compiler for personality "Delphi.Personality" and platform "Win32" missing or unavailable

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, delphi-xe3

After installing Delphi XE3 on HP Probook 4540S notebook (Win 7Prof 64 bit) I have problems while compiling,
The project was an empty VCL project with no components on the form.
At first I received "Invalid PLATFORM variable "BNB". PLATFORM must be one of the following: "Win32", "Win64", or "OSX32".

After have added environmental variable platform=win32 in Environment Options I received compiler error:

compiler for personality "Delphi.Personality" and platform "Win32" missing or unavailable.

What can be done? And why PLATFORM variable has been set to "BNB" during installation? There was nothing in embarcadero site and at Quality Central http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=108487  about this problem,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444064/delphi-xe2-cant-compile-any-project-on-my-computer-because-of-environment-varia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a **Windows** environment variable named `PLATFORM`, likely created by your PC's manufacturer.  Go into the **Windows** environment settings and remove that variable.  Do not use the **IDE** environment settings to override the **Windows** environment variable with a different value.  They are different variables for different purposes, but the **Windows** environment variable is interfering with the **IDE** environment in this situation.

Comment: At http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795530/cannot-load-delphi-xe5-units they advice to override the environment variable in the RAD studio IDE

Comment: Changed the Windows Environment variable Platform to WIN32. in Delphi Env.variables it also became win32. But Compiler error remains,

Comment: Don't change the Windows `PLATFORM` environment variable - GET RID of it instead.  It is not really used for anything, and as long as it exists the IDE will ignore its own `PLATFORM` variable, which gets set dynamically based on which platform you are compiling for.  This is stated in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18800127/65863) to the discussion you linked to. So if you have a Windows `PLATFORM` variable set to Win32, non-Win32 compiles will not work correctly.

Comment: Only deletion of PLATFORM environment variable from Windows Environment variables list resolved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I had no entry in windows env. variables, however it was in my ide env. variables. once i deleted it from there my issue was also resolved